# Почему input больше select?

Tags: html, css

Привет не могу понять где хранятся лишние маргины\паддинги\ещё что-то.. подскажите почему при одинаковой длинне в пикселях input длиннее select?

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/D2hhL/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Установите у обоих:

```
box-sizing:content-box;
-ms-box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing:content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
```

будет отображаться одинаково: http://jsfiddle.net/D2hhL/8/

Comment: в файрфоксе под линукс инпут все одно больше

Comment: @deivan: Обновил ответ, нужно добавить свойства с префиксами.

Comment: Спасибо Павел, вы профессиональный верстальщик?

Comment: @Олег Б: Версткой занимаюсь порядка четырех лет.

Answer (score 0):

Уточняйте где. В Konqueror 4.8 их длины равны. Из чего можно сделать вывод, что это браузерная особенность.

Comment: В основных браузерах (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE, Safari), без установки `box-sizing`, `select` будет на несколько пикселей больше чем `input`. Проблема известная.